# Why does cat produce no output when run asynchronously?

Tags: bash

```
$ echo foo | /usr/bin/cat
foo
$ echo foo | /usr/bin/cat &
[1] 43932
foo
[1]+  Done                    echo foo | /usr/bin/cat
$ echo foo | { /usr/bin/cat & }
$ # NO OUTPUT!!!
$ bash --version | sed 1q
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
$ /usr/bin/cat --version | sed 1q
cat (GNU coreutils) 8.25
```

Is this a bug in bash, or am I missing something obvious?  (Or perhaps I'm missing something subtle!)

Comment: I'd say a bug; I cannot reproduce in 4.4.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious in the release notes addressing this, though.

Comment: My guess would be a change in the way forked shells interact. Since `&` is a *pipeline* terminator, the `{...}`-free version works as expected. *With* `{...}`, the shell that starts `cat` in the background could, in theory, exit before the shell that runs `echo` produces any output, resulting in `cat` not receiving any input. (Not sure if that actually makes sense, since `cat` inherits its standard input from the that shell. I'm not entirely clear on how the various file descriptors are handled.)

Comment: I tested this as well -- works fine on my machine.

Comment: I believe @chepner may be the closest.  If you try your subshell without putting `cat` in the background, `echo foo | { /usr/bin/cat; }`, everything works as expected.  This combined with knowledge that echoing foo without a subshell at all works too, it's a good bet your subshell it dead before echo produces its output.

Comment: Rereading my previous comment, I realize it could also imply that 4.4 *introduced* a bug that keeps the pipe's file descriptor open long enough for `cat` to receive input and produce output. This is (dubiously) supported by the fact that `dash` also fails to produce output with `echo foo | { cat & }`.

Comment: Even if the subshell terminates prior to cat executing, `cat` should keep the file descriptors open and work okay.  Indeed, I get the same behavior with `{ cat & wait; }`, so the subshell termination is (I think) not the issue.

Comment: Perhaps the subshell termination is (incorrectly?) sending SIGHUP to `cat`.

Comment: But strace doesn't show a HUP

Comment: Curious: `echo foo | { sleep 5738 & wait; }`, then using ps to find the pid of the sleep and examining /proc/$pid/fd/0, I see that it is /dev/null!

Comment: (Deleted my previous `strace` example, as I ran that using `bash -c 'cat <<< foo | { cat & }'` instead of `bash -c 'echo foo | { cat & }'`, and it appeared to make a difference.)

Comment: I will stop my ignorant speculating, and just say that I think this is a good question for the `bash` maintainer to resolve: did this fix a bug in earlier versions of `bash`, did `bash` 4.4 introduce a new bug, or does `bash` 4.4 merely provide a new implementation of undefined behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something subtle would be my answer :-)

I would say that this is actually unsupported, according to the documentation (`man` page) for `bash`. The relevant section specifically states (my emphasis):

> `{ list; }` - `list`  is  simply  executed  in the current shell environment.  `list` *must* be terminated with a newline or semicolon.

That "must" clause augments the previous definition of `list`, which is:

> A `list` is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the operators `;`, `&`, `&&`, or `||`, and optionally terminated by one of `;`, `&`, or `<newline>`.

Since you're *not* terminating it with a "newline or semicolon", all bets are off (though I would tend to expect robust software to actually tell you about it rather than just subtly do weird things).

---

If you really want to do that thing in the background, perhaps the easiest thing would be to run the entire *pipeline* in the background rather than trying to do it for just one element of the pipeline:

```
( echo foo | /usr/bin/cat ) &
```